# Unbound sends recursive queries from default gateway

Tags: linux, ubuntu-18.04, unbound

I am looking for an option that will make unbound to send recursive queries from a specific interface.

Listening interface is easy, but I can't find asking interface option.

I have 3 interfaces on my VM and I don't want unbound to ask from default gateway, is there such an option?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found this option from NLNetlabs documentation:

> outgoing-interface: 
> Interface  to  use  to connect to the network. This interface is
> used to send queries to authoritative servers and receive  their
> replies.  Can  be given multiple times to work on several inter-
> faces. If none are given the default  (all)  is  used.  You  can
> specify  the  same  interfaces in interface: and outgoing-inter-
> face: lines, the interfaces are then  used  for  both  purposes.
> Outgoing  queries  are  sent  via a random outgoing interface to
> counter spoofing.

source: https://nlnetlabs.nl/documentation/unbound/unbound.conf/

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to use [Linux Network Namespaces](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ip-netns.8.html):

- create a new network namespace with a separate route table. This route table should contain the default gateway corresponding to your needed network interface;
- run Unbound under this network namespace.

Comment: I wasn't aware of network namespaces. I was planning to write specific routes for each forwarder in worst case scenario. This might save me so much effort, I m gonna check it out. Thank you very much.